# Ember extend just the component template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember JS and have a slightly tricky requirment;

I have to extend a component (not fully in my control). So I plan to use the component JS, but want the template to be in my control (i.e. overwrite what the component provides)

Is that possible ? Does Ember support that? Any reference examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a new component and extend from the one you want extend:

*components/your-component/component.js*

```
import Base from '../base-component/component.js;
export default Base.extend();
```

And then you have your custom template in `components/your-component/template.hbs` that uses the JS code from the base component.

Comment: So I'll get access to the component JS attributes within my own custom template ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to extend using a slightly odd path. For some reason using just the folder path was not sufficient.

```
// The file I was importing was called "component.js", in the "my-component" folder
import MyComponent from 'project/pods/components/my-component/component';

export default MyComponent.extend({
    ...
});
```